# What are the best practices to create a single page app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, singlepage

What are the most important things not to forget or consider when creating a single page app(completely ajax depended) in general? Or any specific consideration on MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Steven Sanderson has a good series of blog posts on single page apps:

- [Layout Basics](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/05/full-height-app-layouts-a-css-trick-to-make-it-easier/)
- [Animated transitions](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/10/12/full-height-app-layouts-animated-transitions-within-panes/)
- [Navigation and history](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/11/04/full-height-app-layouts-navigation-and-history/)

I would also recommend his [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) framework.

Answer (score 0):

For complex projects consider js library - Backbone http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Answer (score 0):

We are using [ExtJs](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) for that.

[ExtJs](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) get all required data from MVC Controllers via JSON.

Answer (score 0):

[DURANDAL](http://durandaljs.com/pages/get-started/) Startkit is a good way to start. Its has MVVM pattern and we can use it with Visual Studio.

Also, Stephen Walther make a good post about security issues. http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2013/03/05/security-issues-with-single-page-apps